# Can't federate components in production mode

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-module-federation

I'm using Angular with [Webpack 5 Module Federation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/) for micro-frontends. I have 2 apps (let's call them app1 and app2) and my main app, app1, is federating components of app2.

In app2, my exposed components are exported by my main module, so when I try to federate some component, I can get it from the export section of my module. Everything works fine in dev mode, I can get my exposed module, retrieve my exported components and then use the [component factory resolver](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver) to create it where I want in app1.

But when I build in production (I used ng serve --prod to reproduce the prod environment and test it) my exported components are gone but not the imports and providers. This is the module I get:

```
MyApp2Module: class e
  ɵfac: ƒ (t)
  ɵinj:
    imports: Array(1)
      0: (12) [ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ]
      length: 1
      [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
    providers: [ƒ]
    [[Prototype]]: Object
  ɵmod:
    bootstrap: []
    declarations: []
    exports: []
    id: null
    imports: []
    schemas: null
    transitiveCompileScopes: null
    type: class e
    [[Prototype]]: Object
```

As you can see, in ɵmod, I have **no exported components** and **no declarations** and I expected to see my components here. I guess it is due to [AOT compilation](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler) and the optimization since it is working in dev mode. Is AOT removing everything in ɵmod on purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by using a static field in my module as suggested [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/21952#issuecomment-945752429).